# What does Trump's usage of "unable to" in this tweet of his indicate/convey?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

[Here's the tweet](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1188067368620167168). Quote:

> [...] to produce & sign into law major Criminal Justice Reform
>   legislation, [...] and which was unable to get done in past
>   administrations

As a non-native English speaker, I would normally phrase that as "couldn't get done".

Comment: Yes; the snag with not using the passive is that a referent has to be specified in the mandatory subject. '... the fine detail on the carving, which the Elbonians couldn't do / get done'. ' ... which was unable to be accomplished under past administrations' distances any blame-attribution, but still sounds clumsy.

Comment: *I would normally phrase that as "couldn't get done."*: Why would you?

Comment: @Kris As I said, I'm a learner of English as a foreign language. It wouldn't have occurred to me to express that thought the way Trump did. Maybe it's just that I have encountered "to be unable to" more frequently in contexts that refer to human beings or physical objects. As in, "I was unable to get my car fixed" or "The robot was unable to defeat the human champion". But in the tweet, "to be unable to" refers to an abstract concept (Criminal Justice Reform legislation).

Comment: I think Trump often goes out of his way to include "questionable" constructions in his tweets, because he likes seeing his political enemies get worked up over such irrelevancies. And they fall for it every time, making themselves look like fools.

Comment: You started by asking a question but ended with the answer. To me, what the tweet conveys is poor grammar and spelling (such as "recieved") skills. The English of many non-native speakers is better than that of the natives.

Comment: It is not incoherent to say, for example, that "The dishes were unable to get done in the past several days." If someone said it to you, you would probably understand the sense of the sentence to be "No one did the dishes in the past several days." However, it is neither an elegant nor a particularly coherent way to express that underlying idea. Indeed, one might argue that the fact that no one did the dishes is not evidence that the dishes were unable to be done, but rather that no one considered doing them to be a sufficiently high priority that they actually performed the task.